# Number of records limited to 1000 (R client on ElasticSearch)

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I'm querying ElasticSearch with R (using elastic client) and it seems I can't reach more than 1000 records. Even if `$hits$total` returns 4187.

Following are the first lines of `str` function when applied to the returned list.

```
List of 4
$ took     : int 1844
$ timed_out: logi FALSE
$ _shards  :List of 3
  ..$ total     : int 692
  ..$ successful: int 692
  ..$ failed    : int 0
$ hits     :List of 3
  ..$ total    : int 4187
  ..$ max_score: num 1
  ..$ hits     :List of 1000
```

If I limit my query to fewer records, I don't get this problem. Following are the first lines of `str` function when applied to the returned list, where we see that `$hits$total` equals the number of returned lists - `$hits$hits`

```
List of 4
$ took     : int 157
$ timed_out: logi FALSE
$ _shards  :List of 3
  ..$ total     : int 692
  ..$ successful: int 692
  ..$ failed    : int 0
$ hits     :List of 3
  ..$ total    : int 13
  ..$ max_score: num 1
  ..$ hits     :List of 13
```

I guess this could be due to some configuration parameter, since this limit is so exact. How can I avoid this limitation and access the all list/number of records?

**EDIT**: (information added)

The parameter `body` is

```
bdy <- '{
"id": "getKpiHistMetric",
"params": {"KpiKey":"Agg:Net|SL,Wind:10min,Net:PT,SL:1,Metric:Rate",
"from": "2016-11-01T00:00:00",
"to": "2016-11-30T23:59:59"}
}'
```

The error apears when interating over the whole list. Firstly I create an empty `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(DATE = integer(),
                 TICK = integer(),
                 VALUE = double(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And then I fill it:

```
for(i in 1:q$hits$total){

  a <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(q$hits$hits[[i]]$`_source`$Timestamp/1000, origin="1970-01-01"), format = "%m/%d/%y")
  b <- strftime(as.POSIXct(round(q$hits$hits[[i]]$`_source`$Timestamp/1000, -1), origin="1970-01-01"), format = "%H:%M")
  c <- q$hits$hits[[i]]$`_source`$Value

  df.row <- data.frame(DATE = a, TICK = b, VALUE = c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df <- rbind(df, df.row)

}
```

At this time I receive the following error:

`Error in q$hits$hits[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`

At this time, `i = 1001`

Comment: you should be able to do up to 10000 with default ES config. did you use the `size` parameter? or you can do that in the body

Comment: that error doesn't have much to do with the `elastic` pkg, that's just that within your for loop you are trying to index on the results from ES where there are no longer any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the number of records is limited to `1000` is due to elasticsearch configuration. This was the answer I got from database maintenance team.